# WildFly and old EJB2 code

Tags: java, ejb-2.x, wildfly

We have a project with plenty of legacy EJB2 stuff along with new code written in EJB3.
So we want to migrate it from JBoss AS 7 to WildFly.

Does WildFly support EJB2?

I have tried to find info about this, but found only info from June 10 2013 that

> "Support ... has been made optional in this release and their description is moved to a separate EJB Optional Features document"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EJB 2 is a required part of Java EE 7, thus WildFly definitely supports EJB 2, with the exception of (now-optional) container-managed persistence (also known as "entity beans") support.

Comment: Thank you David, than I'll try to deploy our project and will accept your answer if it works!

Comment: dds, Do you still use ejb2 cmp (entity beans) in your project (with wildfly)?

Comment: Sriram, yes, we have legacy code (EJB2) mixed with new components (EJB3). It works on Wildfly 8.1.0.